# VueJS : Getting innerHTML of custom component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to build very simple bootstrap alert component but Iam unable to figure out how to get `innerHTML` of my custom component.

Code:

```
Vue.component('my-alert', {
  template: '#vue-alert',
  props: ['type', 'title', 'message'],
  created: function() {        
    this.message = this.innerHTML; // <---- NOT WORKING
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: 'body'
});
```

HTML:

```
<my-alert type="success" title="Important">My Message here.</my-alert>
```

I want to show the component whatever text is provided in it, in this case it should show `My Message here.`

[Here is example of it](http://jsbin.com/belumipatu/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay I figured out, I needed to use the [`<slot></slot>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

```
<template id="vue-alert">
  <div v-if="show" class="alert alert-{{type}} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button @click="removeAlert" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <strong>{{title}}!</strong> <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```